# Модальные окна и php

Tags: php, bootstrap, alert, modal

Хочу сделать отзывчивый пользовательский интерфейс. Есть форма, которая собирает данные, отправляет на сервер. Скрипт что-то делает и на каждый шаг выдает, что-то типа:

```
echo "Succsessful!"
```

И таких выводов несколько в коде:

```
if ($opt == "create") {
    $db_link = @mysqli_connect($link, $user, $pass);
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $db . " CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;";
    if (mysqli_query($db_link, $sql)) {
        echo "База успешно создана\n";
    } else {
        echo "Ощибка при создании базы данных: " . mysqli_error($db_link);
    }
} 

    $db_link = @mysqli_connect($link, $user, $pass, $db);

    if (!$db_link) {echo "Не удалось установить связь с базой данных: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." \n"; die();}
    echo "Связь с базой данных установлена\n";
```

На стороне клиента вывод пока через console.log(). И данные выводятся единым текстом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал через alert, и выводится только последнее сообщение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
$("#submit").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $("form").serialize();

    $.get("php/init.php", formData, function(data){
        createModal(data);
    })
})
```

Создание div'а:

```
function createModal(content) {
    $("<div>", {
        text: content,
        class: "alert alert-success greenPaper"
    }).appendTo("body").delay(1000).show(function() {
        $(".alert").fadeOut(function() {
            $(".alert").remove();
        });         
    });         
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы каждый echo выводился в свой alert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перенос убери, или бордюр поставь

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `\n` используйте `<br>`, вы же теперь в HTML отдаёте.